# 3 columns layout using float, the element of the third column are over the middle column

Tags: css

I have a layout with 3 columns.

The columns are done using floats. I want the first column to be aligned left, the middle colum (button) to be aligned, in the center and the last column to align to the right.

I don't use flexbox, because I need to support older IE(9).

The problem, that I have is the last column is over the middle column.

The input in the third column, I want to have a 'flexible' width.

One smaller screen I want the middle column to be hidden.

```css
.container {
margin: 1.5rem 0 0;
}

.l-left {

    float: left;
    width: 55%;

}
.l-middle {

    float: left;
    width: 10%;

}
.l-right {

    float: right;
    width: 35%;

}

.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container clearfix">
  <div class="l-left">
    <ul class="list-inline">
        <li class="list-inline-item">lorem ipsum</li>
        <li class="list-inline-item">lorem ipsum</li>
        <li class="list-inline-item">lorem ipsum</li>
        <li class="list-inline-item">lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="l-middle">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Add container Free</a>
  </div>
  <div class="l-right">
    <form action="/contact" method="post" >
      <input class="input" type="text" name="email">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe a typo ? `l-fright` should be `l-right` ? and `One smaller screen ` what does that mean ? how ' small ' ?

Comment: What is the style for `.container`?

Comment: @MihaiT thanks, it is not the typo; small - not a clear resolution, I will define it, in the sense is to small to be usable/visible

Comment: @NemanjaGlumac is just a div with a margin, I updated

Comment: I have run the code here and I have tried it on Codepen. Right column isn't hiding the middle one. The content of the middle column (button) is overflowing. If you add borders to the columns (for test purposes), you will see they are not overlapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original question you have `l-fright` in css but it should've been `l-right`. Also, the text of the button doesn't always fit in that `10%` width. You can either use a small font-size, or less text inside that button or use `word-break:break-word` or `white-space:unset` or some combination between the two. It all depends on what you want your layout to look like.

You say on ' smaller ' screens you want the middle column to disappear. Use media queries for that.

I hid it from 500px down.

See snippet below or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c8k5Lm2r/1/) ( where you can play around with screen size )

```css
.l-left {
  float: left;
  width: 55%;
}

.l-middle {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
}

.l-middle a {
  white-space: unset;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.l-right {
  float: right;
  width: 35%;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .l-middle {
    display: none;
  }
  .l-right {
    width: 45%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container clearfix">
  <div class="l-left">
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li class="list-inline-item">lorem ipsum</li>
      <li class="list-inline-item">lorem ipsum</li>
      <li class="list-inline-item">lorem ipsum</li>
      <li class="list-inline-item">lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="l-middle">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Add container Free</a>
  </div>
  <div class="l-right">
    <form action="/contact" method="post">
      <input class="input" type="text" name="email">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```